# Ranges surrounding values in data frame R dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, range, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks something like this :

```
test <- data.frame(chunk = c(rep("a",27),rep("b",27)), x = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

There is a column by which I would like to group the data using `group_by()` in `dplyr`, which in this example is called `chunk`

I want to add another column to each chunk of `test` called `x1` so the resulting data frame looks like this :

```
test1 <- data.frame(test, x1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

`x1` identifies all of the occurrences of 0 in `x` and takes a range of +-5 rows in each direction from the end 0s and adds an identifier. What the identifier is doesn't matter, but in this example the identifier in `x1` is 1 for the range and 2 for the occurrences of 0 in `x`

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option to do it in `dplyr`:

Shorter version:

```
n <- 1:5
test %>%
  group_by(chunk) %>%  
  mutate(x1 = ifelse((row_number() - min(which(x == 0))) %in% -n |
       (row_number(chunk) - max(which(x == 0))) %in% n, 1, ifelse(x == 0, 2, 0)))
```

Longer (first) version:

```
test %>%
  group_by(chunk) %>%
  mutate(start = (row_number() - min(which(x == 0))) %in% -5:-1,
         end = (row_number() - max(which(x == 0))) %in% 1:5,
         x1 = ifelse(start | end, 1, ifelse(x == 0, 2, 0))) %>%
  select(-c(start, end))

Source: local data frame [54 x 3]
Groups: chunk

   chunk x x1
1      a 1  0
2      a 1  0
3      a 1  0
4      a 1  0
5      a 1  0
6      a 1  0
7      a 1  0
8      a 1  1
9      a 1  1
10     a 1  1
11     a 1  1
12     a 1  1
13     a 0  2
14     a 0  2
15     a 0  2
16     a 0  2
17     a 1  1
18     a 1  1
19     a 1  1
20     a 1  1
21     a 1  1
22     a 1  0
23     a 1  0
24     a 1  0
25     a 1  0
26     a 1  0
27     a 1  0
28     b 1  0
29     b 1  0
30     b 1  0
31     b 1  0
32     b 1  0
33     b 1  0
34     b 1  0
35     b 1  1
36     b 1  1
37     b 1  1
38     b 1  1
39     b 1  1
40     b 0  2
41     b 0  2
42     b 0  2
43     b 0  2
44     b 1  1
45     b 1  1
46     b 1  1
47     b 1  1
48     b 1  1
49     b 1  0
50     b 1  0
51     b 1  0
52     b 1  0
53     b 1  0
54     b 1  0
```

The assumption in this approach is, that in each group of "chunk" there is only one sequence of 0s (as in the sample data). Let me know if that's not the case in your actual data.