# dplyr row_number() behavior in boolean operation

Tags: r, dplyr

While answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415587/ranges-surrounding-values-in-data-frame-r-dplyr/25429971#25429971) I encountered a behavior of `dplyr::row_number()` which was a bit surprising to me and I wonder if that is supposed to be the behavior and for what reason. Here's an example: I want to make two logical tests connected by OR or AND involving the function `row_number()`. Here's a simple example that doesn't make much sense but illustrates what I mean:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  mutate(newcol = row_number() - Sepal.Length < 0 | row_number() - Petal.Length < 0)
Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

As you can see, it returns an error. Running each part of the boolean test individually runs perfectly fine. And, to solve the problem, I need to add the column to which the *second* `row_number` should refer, for example both of these modifications work:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(newcol = row_number() - Sepal.Length < 0 | row_number(Species) - Petal.Length < 0)
```

Or

```
iris %>%
  mutate(newcol = row_number(Species) - Sepal.Length < 0 | row_number(Species) - Petal.Length < 0)
```

I wonder if this is a programmatic necessity or not or why `row_number` doesn't just use the same input after the `|` as it does before. Can someone help me understand this?

(I'm running `dplyr` 0.2, R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10), RStudion Version 0.98.977)

Edit:

Could also be demonstrated here:

```
iris %>% mutate(test = 1 == 1 | row_number() < 10)
iris %>% mutate(test = 1 == 1 | row_number(Species) < 10)
iris %>% mutate(test = row_number() < 10 | 1 == 1)
```

Edit 2:

Adding to my confusion is that

```
iris %>% mutate(test = TRUE | row_number() < 10)  # works
iris %>% mutate(test = FALSE | row_number() < 10) # also works
```

but

```
iris %>% mutate(test = 1 == 1 | row_number() < 10) # throws error
iris %>% mutate(test = 1 == 2 | row_number() < 10) # also throws error
```

Comment: Can you please file a issue on github?

Comment: @hadley, sure, here it is: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/554) has been closed with [this commit](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/4afde1e1b46e2c4127393574877e72421c6da629).

The [current version available on CRAN at the time of this answer](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) is version 0.3.0.2. This version demonstrates the behavior you are expecting.

```
temp <- iris %>%
  mutate(newcol = row_number() - Sepal.Length < 0 | 
           row_number() - Petal.Length < 0)
head(temp)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species newcol
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   TRUE
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   TRUE
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   TRUE
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   TRUE
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  FALSE
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  FALSE
```